# Solo se guarda la primera palabra, en las demás se cierra el BufferedWriter

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo un programa que me cree una ventana gráfica con tres componentes: dos `JButton` y un `JTextField`, asignando un evento a cada botón:

- El primer botón me abre un `JFileChooser` para abrir un bloc de notas.
- El segundo botón me deja guardar el texto en el bloc de notas que previamente he abierto en el botón 1.

El problema está en que solo me guarda la primera palabra, en las demás me cierra el `BufferedWriter` y no entiendo el porqué. Os comparto el código para ver en que estoy fallando y por qué.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class VentanaFrame implements ActionListener, WindowListener {
    
    private JButton boton1;
    private JButton boton2;
    private JTextField texto;
    private File archivo;
    private BufferedWriter bw;
    
    public VentanaFrame() {
        
        boton1 = new JButton("Abrir Archivo");
        boton2 = new JButton("Guardar texto");
        texto = new JTextField();
        
    }
    
    public void Ejecuta() {
        
        //creo la ventana grafica
        JFrame ventana = new JFrame("Ventana");
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ventana.setSize(400, 350);
        ventana.setLocation(450, 400);
        ventana.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ventana.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        
        //creo el Panel
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        
        //creo el tamaño de los botones
        
        boton1.setSize(50,50);
        boton2.setSize(50,50);
        
        //indico el tamaño del texto
        
        texto.setColumns(20);
        
        //añado los componentes al panel
        
        panel.add(boton1);
        panel.add(boton2);
        panel.add(texto);
        
        //añado los eventos a los componentes
        
        boton1.addActionListener(this);
        boton2.addActionListener(this);
        texto.addActionListener(this);
        
        
        //añado el panel a la ventana
        ventana.add(panel);
        
        //hago visible la ventana
        ventana.setVisible(true);
    }   
    
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        
        if(event.getSource() == boton1) {
            
            JFileChooser elegirArchivo = new JFileChooser();
            elegirArchivo.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
            elegirArchivo.setDialogTitle("Selecciona el fichero");
            
            int returnVal = elegirArchivo.showDialog(elegirArchivo,"Cargar");
            
            if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                
                archivo = elegirArchivo.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    
                    this.bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo));
                    
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al abrir el archivo");
                    
                }
            }
            
            else if(returnVal == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has cancelado la operacion.");
            }
            
        }
        
        else if(event.getSource() == boton2 || event.getSource() == texto) {
            
            try {
                bw.write(texto.getText() + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error en la escritura del archivo");
            }
            
            if(null != bw) {
                
                try {
                    bw.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar el Buffer");
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent event) {
        
        if(null != bw){
            
            try {
                bw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al cerrar el buffer");
            }
            
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> El problema está en que solo me guarda la primera palabra, en las
> demás me cierra el bufferedWriter y no entiendo el porqué.

Ten en cuenta que:

1. Si solo se esta guardando la ultima linea que se introduce es porque `FileWriter` no esta haciendo el *append* sobre el archivo, lo esta sobre-escribiendo (*es el comportamiendo default*), se soluciona usando su constructor [`FileWriter(File file,boolean append);`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File,boolean))
2. Despues de cerrar el *stream* del `BufferedWriter` no hay vuelta atras para que se pueda volver a escribir en el archivo, lo mas adecuado es volver a crear una instancia `BufferedWriter` cada que se vaya a efectuar una escritura sobre el archivo en cuestion.

Quedando algo parecido a lo siguiente en el bloque que escribe los datos:

```
//...
try {
  bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(archivo,true));
  bw.write(texto.getText() + "\n");
} catch (IOException e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error en la escritura del archivo\n"
                                    +e.getMessage());
}
//...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ya se me solucionó el problema y me deja escribir correctamente, no sabía que era por el append ni que me lo estaba sobreescribiendo.